Having trouble connecting to openai api with the API Key in power query editor of power bi
i have defined a function for sending the prompt inputs to open ai api for getting the prompt response
let  Output = (message as text) as text =>
let
    url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions",
    apikey = "my-api-key",
    headers = [
        #"Content-Type" = "application/json",
        #"Authorization" = "Bearer " & apikey
    ],
    body = Json.FromValue([
        model  ="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages = [
            role = "user",
            content = message
        ],
        temperature = 0.7, // Example temperature value (adjust as needed)
        max_tokens = 100 // Example max_tokens value (adjust as needed)
    ]),
    response = Web.Contents(url, [Headers = headers, Content = body]),
    content = Json.Document(response)[choices]{0}[message][content]
in content
in Output

after passing the prompt to the function i should get the result in a simple step
i am getting an error please specify how to connect , out of the available options like anoymous, windows,Basic, webapi, and organizational account , i have selected webapi
in Web Api there is an input box for the Key and a dropdown where i can select the parts of the URL,
i have pasted my apikey in the input box and selected the full url of openai api
i am getting the below error

